# search model yii2

Tags: yii2

как в search model yii2 задать вывод из таблицы диапазона цены от 0 до 1500 по таблице product(колонка price)?

Comment: `$query->andFilterWhere(['BETWEEN',  'price', 0, 1500]);` OR `$query->andFilterWhere(['<=',  'price', 1500]);`

Comment: спасибо добрый человек